# IntelliJ - How to find classes in a *specific* module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So ... there's `Ctrl + N` to search for classes

Is there any way to tell it to search in a *specific* module?

I know I can select *a* module in the drop-down at the top, but the module is fixed and cannot be changed (and conveniently is never the module I DO want to search in).

Also does not correspond to the module I'm currently working in, so I have no idea how IntelliJ selects the module it puts in there.

I know I can `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and search for the class declarations in the module I want,

But am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctrl+Shift+N to "Find File" and prefix your search with part of the module name... I.E. I have to find MyDemoApplication in the module my-demo-module, I can type the following: demo/my 
or demo/MDA can work too.

I cannot post images yet, so you can look at this if you like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkD6R.jpg